# Trimming the unused items from buffer[] before fwrite

Tags: c, fwrite

I am creating a file with the content depending on some local variables. I don't know how long the file will be at the end. Since I define a `buffer[]` array with a fixed size, the last characters in the generated file are garbage. How should I trim `buffer[]` array before writing it to the file? Or `fwrite` only the used bytes?

Here is my code:

```
FILE * pFile = NULL;
char buffer[300];
int ret_val = -1;
strcpy_s(buffer, "The path is \"");
strcat_s(buffer, pathVariable);
strcat_s(buffer, "\"\n");
pFile = fopen(myfile, "w");
if(NULL == pFile)
{
  perror("File opening error");
  return -1;
}
ret_val = fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), pFile );
if(sizeof(buffer) != ret_val)
{
  perror("File writing error");
  return -1;
}
fclose(pFile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fwrite()` doesn't know which bytes you consider "used". When you call it like so:

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), pFile );
```

it will write `sizeof(buffer)` bytes.

Change the call to:

```
ret_val = fwrite(buffer, 1, used_bytes, pFile );
```

where `used_bytes` is some variable that you set before the call.

You'll also need to alter the subsequent error check:

```
if(ret_val != used_bytes)
```

**edit** In this case, it would appear you'd want to set `used_bytes` to `strlen(buffer)`.

Comment: I don't want to do something like `int used_bytes = sizeof("The path is \"") + sizeof(pathVariable) + sizeof("\"\n");` because someone can change the string in `strcpy` and forget to change it here. `strcpy` and `strcat` set the unused bytes to -2. Perhaps, I should check where -2's start.

Comment: @mustafa: I suspect in your case you just want `strlen(buffer)`.

Comment: yes, it was exactly what I needed. I needed to use `fwrite(buffer, 1, strlen(buffer), pFile );`

Answer (score 1):

The third argument passed to `fwrite()` is the number of bytes to write, so instead of writing using:

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), pFile )
```

count the number of bytes you really want to write, then do:

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, numBytesToWrite, pFile )
```